# Getting error No component factory found for component with lazyloading when calling ComponentFactoryResolver

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically load a component inside a modal-popup using ComponentFactoryResolver with lazyLoading.
But I am getting the error: No component factory found for ConfirmationComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Although the ConfirmationComponent is already added in entryComponents. The showModal function is called from within the profilepage component and passes the component to a service inside the app.module with a rxjs subject.

In the modal component there is a subscription to this subject and passess this to the ComponentFactoryResolver.

The modal does work if it's not used with seperate modules/lazyloading.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'la' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ModalService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

profile.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    ProfilePageComponent,
    ConfirmationComponent,
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,
    SharedModule
],
providers: [],
entryComponents: [
    ConfirmationComponent,
],
})

export class ProfileModule { }
```

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    ModalComponent,
],
imports: [
    CommonModule
],
providers: [],
exports: [ModalComponent],
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

profile-page.component I am passing the component from here to a service

```
modal.service component from the shared.module
@Component({
  selector: 'la-profile-page',
  templateUrl: './profile-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-page.component.scss']
})

export class ProfilePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  confirm(certificate: Certificate) {
    this.modalService.setComponent(ConfirmationComponent, {}, {});
  }
}
```

modal.servce.ts

```
@Injectable()

export class ModalService {

  public componentChanged = new Subject<any>();
  componentChanged$ = this.componentChanged.asObservable();

  constructor(
  ) { }

  setComponent(component: any, inputs: any = {}, outputs: any = {}) {
    this.componentChanged.next({ component: component, inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setComponent(null, {}, {});
  }

}
```

modal.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'la-modal',
  styleUrls: ['modal.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: 'modal.component.html',
  animations: [modalAnimation]
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  component = null;
  show = false;

  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private controller: ModalService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.controller.componentChanged$.subscribe(component => {
      this.setComponent(component.component, component.inputs, component.outputs);
    });
  }

  setComponent(component: any, inputs: any, outputs: any) {
    if (!component) {
      this.show = false;
      return;
    } else {
      this.show = true;
    }

    const inputProviders = Object.keys(inputs).map((inputName) => {
      return {
        provide: inputName,
        useValue: inputs[inputName]
      };
    });

    const outputProviders = Object.keys(outputs).map((outputName) => {
      return {
        provide: outputName,
        useValue: outputs[outputName]
      };
    });

    const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);
    const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);
    console.log(component);
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

    if (this.component) {
      this.component.destroy();
    }

    this.component = factory.create(injector);
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(this.component.hostView);

    inputProviders.forEach(prov => {
      this.component.instance[prov.provide] = prov.useValue;
    });

    outputProviders.forEach(prov => {
      this.component.instance[prov.provide].subscribe(prov.useValue);
    });

  }

  closeModal() {
    this.show = false;
  }

  deleteComponent(event) {
    // this will be triggered when @modal.animation is done
    if (event.fromState) {
      this.dynamicComponentContainer.clear();
      this.component = null;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: We're going to need a little bit more than three pieces of code to help you. for instance, a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Ah ok i'll add more to it. I was thinking it was more of an issue from how the modules/components are shared and lazyloaded. I'll add the service and modal component in a bit.

Comment: Yes and no. For instance, creating a component portal from the CDK automatically a component factory resolver, but for dynamically created components following the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), you have to do it by hand. So if we don't know the full implementation, we can't really help you.

Comment: I have added more code to it

Comment: Again, try making a [mcve] : most of the time, you resolve your issue by yourself. Try with https://stackblitz.com. In the meantime, I'm looking at your code to see potential errors.